# iPhone unread counts on tabbar

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, email, sms, tabbar

Which is the best way to implement on Cocoa Touch the unread counts on a icon on a TabBar?

I want to mimic the SMS or Mail application behavior, showing the unread message count to the user of my application, with a red dot containing a number.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The property you're looking for is called the badge.  You set it by doing something like:

```
self.tabBarItem.badgeValue = @"1";
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at: setApplicationBadgeNumber?

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationBadgeNumber:int];
```

Answer (score 1):

For current view I use:

```
self.navigationController.tabBarItem.badgeValue = @"5";
```