# iPhone unread dots on homescreen on web app icon

Tags: web-applications, iphone, favicon

I'd like to know if it is possible to have unread dots on a icon of a iwebkit-based webapp.

I've read this but its for native apps. Is it possible to simulate this with javascript or something?
[iPhone unread counts on tabbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610172/iphone-unread-counts-on-tabbar)

[image]
<sub>(source: [iphone3g-india.com](http://iphone3g-india.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/taskbar-notifier-iphone1.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, only native applications can do this.